# Get co-ordinates from existing line in Open Layers

Tags: openlayers

I'm quite new to Open Layers but i have suceeded in drawing lines and polygones with help from: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html

I wonder how do i get the longitude and latitude from a vector? 
I saw a explanation here: [how to get co-ordinates of vector layer line points from openlayers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573810/how-to-get-co-ordinates-of-vector-layer-line-points-from-openlayers) 
but I'm to new to make it work.

Can anyone help me with the code or provide an example?

EDIT: 
Here is the solution.

```
function lineAdded(feature) {
    var nodes = feature.geometry.getVertices();

    for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    var lon = nodes[i].x;
    var lat = nodes[i].y;
    console.log("lon: "+lon+", lat"+lat);
    }
}
lineControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors, path, {'featureAdded': lineAdded});
```

Answer (score 0):

hi 
you can take feauture of your point by:

```
map.vectorLayer.features[i]
```

you can select one by one your vector feature with for loop ...
but first of all what u want to do? yo wanna selected point feature or another thing?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply.  Basicly what i want to do is to store the LonLat coordinates for later use. I succeeded with this by adding a callback as this. `code`function lineAdded(feature) {
    var nodes = feature.geometry.getVertices();
    
    for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
 var lon = nodes[i].x;
 var lat = nodes[i].y;
 console.log("lon: "+lon+", lat"+lat);
    }
} lineControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors, path, {'featureAdded': lineAdded});`code`

Comment: It looks as though you have the coordinates in that loop then? Where do you run into trouble after that?

Comment: Acctually that code solved it! So there are no more trouble. I just wich i could format the code a little better so others could use it because i have seen this question a lot but no real, simple solution before.